# Python search custom European time

Tags: python, python-3.x, dateparser

I'm trying to parse string on Spanish language and get datetime from it.
Is any way to put date format that needs to be searched?

```
from dateparser.search import search_dates

settings = {'DATE_ORDER': 'MDY'}

string = "26.03.2020 (datos consolidados a las 21:00 horas del 25.03.2020)"
time = search_dates(string, settings=settings)[-1]

print(time)
```

Output:

```
('21:00 horas del 25.03.2020', datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 26, 0, 0))
```

Expected Output:

```
('21:00 horas del 25.03.2020', datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 25, 21, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the *date_formats* argument of [`dateparser.parse()`](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#dateparser.parse).